# How to check a string to see if it contains an 8 or a 9 in Java

Tags: java, string, loops, contains

I have a project for school where I have to check an octal number and reject it if it's not octal, and I've no clue how to run a loop to do this. I'm a beginner.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String octalNum;

    System.out.print("Please enter a postive octal number: ");
    octalNum = in.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < octalNum.length(); i++) {
        if (octalNum.charAt(i) == 8 || octalNum.charAt(i) == 9) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a postive octal number: ");
            octalNum = in.next();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must show some effort.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < octalNum.length(); i++) {
            if (octalNum.charAt(i) == 8 || octalNum.charAt(i) == 9) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a postive octal number: ");
                octalNum = in.next();
            }
        }

Comment: How would you do it by hand? Get a pencil and piece of paper, and I suggest you consider your valid inputs (i.e. '0'-'7') more then possible invalid inputs.

Comment: Replace 8 with '8', the same applies to 9. You work with characters here not integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. Just keep in mind that [`String.charAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) returns a `char` not an `int`. Because of that, you should check for `'number'` instead. Thus, 8 becomes '8' and 9 becomes '9'.